# How to set "onPress" 's Switch Toggle library in React Native with typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native

I need to use a switch toggle in my App (library git: dooboolab/react-native-switch-toggle). I'm using typescript in react-native. I get an error when I set the function for the onPress gestureResponderEvent. It says: type void is not assignable to type boolean.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import SwitchToggle form 'react-native-switch-toggle';
import {View} from 'react-native';

export default class Login extends Component{

  state = {
    switchOn : false
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <View>
        <SwitchToggle 
            switchOn={this.state.switchOn}
            onPress = {this.onPress1}  //HERE THE ERROR
        />
      </View>
    )
  }

  onPress1 = () =>{
     this.setState({switchOn:!this.state.switchOn});
  }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: on the onPress1 function can you add a return false; statement and try it

Comment: It doesn't work yet

Answer (score 0):

onPress is unable to react the function.
Call the function from onPress like this

> onPress = {() =>this.onPress1() }

Comment: Now it says: Type void is not assignable to type '{}'

Comment: Type '() => void' is not assignable to type '(event:GestureResponderEvent) => {}'.
Type 'void' is not assignable to type '{}'.

Comment: put your onPress in the parent view                                                                 <View onPress = {this.onPress1}>
        <SwitchToggle 
            switchOn={this.state.switchOn}
        />
      </View>

Comment: Property onPress is missing in type[...]

Answer (score 0):

You need to type your `onPress1` method with the same signature that `onPress` prop has. `SwitchToggle`'s `onPress` has the following signature:

```
onPress: (event: GestureResponderEvent) => {};
```

So in order for you to pass `this.onPress1` to `onPress` prop, you'd need to write your `onPress1` in this manner:

```
onPress1 = (event: GestureResponderEvent) => {
   // do stuff
};
```

Then in your JSX:

```
<SwitchToggle onPress={this.onPress1} />
```

Comment: in //do stuff I put this: this.setState({switchOn:!this.state.switchOn});
Still does not work...